# Spring :How to handle transactions for DB operations across services

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

I am trying to understand how I can introduce transactions across services in Spring.

I have organization class and every organization will have a associated superadmin.
I am creating an organization and then creating super user for it.
But I would like to execute these in a transaction, i.e if super admin creation fails, then organization row which got inserted by createOrganization() method should be rolled back.
I am using JOOQ to handle DB operations.

How can I achieve transactions across services(organizationService and userService) ?

```
addSuperAdmin(Organization organizationObject, SuperUser superUserObject)
{
    String orgId = organizationService.createOrganization(organizationObject);
    superUserObject.orgId = orgId;
    userService.AddSuperAdminDetailsToDB(superUserObject);
}
```

Comment: The fact that you're using jOOQ is probably not relevant to this question, as you will be using Spring to manage your transactions, not jOOQ or JDBC...

Comment: @LukasEder I am trying to use JOOQ's transaction management.

Comment: But why? When you're using Spring, why not just use Spring's transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to mix Spring's dependency injection and configuration of (transactional?) data sources with jOOQ's transaction API. That is a path you will probably regret many times.

jOOQ's transaction API works like this:

```java
// Some pre-configured DSLContext with a Configuration
ctx1.transaction(config2 -> {
    // A derived, transactional DSLContext with a derived Configuration
    config2.dsl().insertInto(...).execute();
});
```

The idea is that you're passing around *derived* `Configuration` objects which contain their transactional state. The *original* `Configuration` object (`ctx1` in my example) is unaware of any transactions that have been started.

This is quite different from how Spring models thread-bound transactions that are updated based on whether you're entering a `@Transactional` annotated method, which updates the global transaction state for your thread context.

Since you're probably injecting a jOOQ `DSLContext` containing a `Configuration` and a `DataSource` to all your services, you must remove that again, and pass around the transactional `DSLContext` that you *prefer* to use instead. It's not impossible, but it's just not idiomatic in the "Spring world". Every time you forget this, you'll pay the price by having a jOOQ transaction, a separate Spring transaction, and the two things being unaware of each other.

Why not just use Spring's `@Transactional` annotations everywhere, instead?

Comment: Thanks Lukas. I have started using @Transactional now.